# ColdFusion: Insert Date Time in One Variable Into Database Oracle10

Tags: sql, datetime, variables, coldfusion, oracle10g

I have stuck with this problem for one hour. I am using ColdFusion language. In my code, I want to insert datetime into my database Oracle. Datetime format will look like this:

```
<cfset form.date_print = #dateFormat(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & timeFormat(now(), "HH:mm:ss")#>
```

and function to insert my datetime into my database will look like this:

```
<cfset qAdd = APPLICATION.qbs.insertData(column:'date_print,usr_id_print,qsd_id,loc_id',formData:'#FORM#',table:"qpl_print_log")>
```

In my table, format for attribute date_print is `DATE`.

This is snapshot when I click button to insert datetime into my database Oracle:

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is function to insert data to the database

```
<cffunction name="insertData" access="public" returntype="struct" output="no">
  <cfargument name="column"  required="true" type="string" hint="data">
  <cfargument name="value"  required="false" type="string" hint="data">
  <cfargument name="formData"  required="false" type="struct" hint="data">
  <cfargument name="table"  required="true" type="string" hint="table">
  <cfargument name="dateType"  required="false" type="string">
  <cfargument name="sqlNvarcharType"  required="false" type="string">
  <cfargument name="returnID"  required="true" type="boolean" default="true">
  <cfargument name="db"  required="false" type="string" hint="data" default="#variables.db.db_datasource_ro#">

  <cfset var local           = {}>
  <cfset local.counter       = 0>
  <cfset local.return        = {}>
  <cfset local.return.status = "OK">
  <cfset local.return.id     = 0>
  <cfset local.return.cuid = APPLICATION.cuid.getCUID()>
  <cfif ListFind(column,"submit")>
    <cfset column = ListDeleteAt( column, ListFind(column,"submit")) >
  </cfif>

  <cftry>
    <cfquery name="local.insertData" datasource="#db#" result="myresult">
      INSERT INTO  #table#(#column#,cuid) VALUES(
        <cfif isDefined('Arguments.value') AND Arguments.value NEQ "">
          <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(Arguments.value,';')#" index="item">
            <cfif isDefined('Arguments.dateType') AND ListFind(dateType,item)><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#convertDate(trim(listGetAt(value, item,';')))#">
            <cfelseif isDefined('Arguments.sqlNvarcharType') AND ListFind(sqlNvarcharType,item)><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#trim(listGetAt(value, item,';'))#">
            <cfelse><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#trim(listGetAt(value, item,';'))#"></cfif><cfif item LT ListLen(column)>,</cfif>
          </cfloop>
        <cfelse>
          <cfloop list="#column#" index="theField">
            <cfset local.counter = local.counter+1>
            <cfif isDefined('Arguments.dateType') AND ListFind(dateType,theField)><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#convertDate(formData[theField])#">
            <cfelseif isDefined('Arguments.sqlNvarcharType') AND ListFind(sqlNvarcharType,theField)><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#trim(formData[theField])#">
            <cfelse><cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(formData[theField])#"></cfif><cfif local.counter LT ListLen(column)>,</cfif>
          </cfloop>
        </cfif>
      ,'#local.return.cuid#')
    </cfquery>

    <cfif Arguments.returnID EQ true>
        <cfquery name="qetAutoIncrementID" datasource="#db#">
          SELECT id
          FROM #table#
          WHERE cuid = '#local.return.cuid#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfset local.return.id = qetAutoIncrementID.id>
    </cfif>

    <cfcatch>
        <cfset local.return.status = "BAD">
        <cfset local.return.cfcatch = cfcatch>
        <cfset APPLICATION.db.notifyError(functionname:"Insert:#table#", args:ARGUMENTS, cfcatch:cfcatch)>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfreturn local.return>
</cffunction>
```

In my table, attribute date_print show `date format` only.

[image]

But in ColdFusion, I send the format date and time like this `2016-05-16 14:12:35`.

But If I want to see my time format, I need to click the pencil icon.

[image]

Hope anyone can help me to fix this problem.

Thank you

Comment: I do not have any experience of oracle but seems oracle store data in DD-MM-YY format. please have a look at documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847

Comment: Basically I do not think that ColdFusion can't read the date and time format. What I think is it getting an error while execute to the database. I am not really sure how to solve this problem. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: CF can read date and time but you mentioned that you have problem inserting data into the database so it may be. Second thing you have not posted the query that is inserting the data.

Comment: @Keshavjha I already update my post. Can you see anything problem?

Comment: If all you want to do is insert the current date and time into your Oracle db, forget ColdFusion and use the Oracle object, `sysdate`.

Comment: And one other thing I just noticed on the code review side, your public method is returning the cfcatch of your database call. Log your error inside your system, but don't return much more than "Uh oh." An error dump gives a whole bunch of information to people who don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `cfsqltype as cf_sql_date`. You need to pass `CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP` as your cfsqltype.

Your cfqueryparam should look like this:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#convertDate(trim(listGetAt(value, item,';')))#">
```

cf_sql_date truncates date-time to just a date value (actually evaluates as a numeric value) where as cf_sql_timestamp uses a full date time stamp.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. By default my team used this code: `<cfset form.date_print = #dateFormat(now(), 'dd-mmm-yy')#>` but it seems like getting date only. So I changed the code like this:  `<cfset form.date_print = #dateFormat(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & timeFormat(now(), "HH:mm:ss")#>` . I still getting an error.

Comment: @FaiZalDong, Why are you formatting dates when inserting in the database. Date formatting are for display purposes. It doesn't matter what date format you pass to database, database will store dates according to its own convention. You should just use <cfset form.date_print = now()>

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of things going on here.

Oracle stores DATE datatypes with values for century, year, month, day, hour, minute and second. Kinda different that MS SQL's epoch storage, but you still have access to your time values in a date datatype. If you need more precision, TIMESTAMP datatype provides you down to I think 5 or 6 digits after the decimal (so lots of milliseconds).

For storing the datetime, Tushar is correct. You should use CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP instead of just CF_SQL_DATE. For Oracle, the TIMESTAMP value will give you the hour:minute:second precision you're looking for. Oracle is very datatype sensitive (whereas MS SQL can be more forgiving sometimes), and I believe a CF_SQL_DATE (which will work in MSSQL) is returned as an integer with the time portion truncated (giving you 0 hr, 0 min and 0 sec), and CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP is an actual timestamp object that Oracle (and other databases, like SQL Server) can better understand. So use TIMESTAMP instead of DATE.

The truncation is why you are seeing the 0:0:0 when you click to edit the value.

Your query tool itself is why you are seeing the date formatted the way you are. 
I'm not sure which one you are using, but to change the display in SQL Developer, go to Tools >> Preferences >> Click NLS > Edit Date Format with the mask you want to use (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS). This will display your query with your desired date format. TOAD or others should have something similar.

About halfway down the page is a chart with the applicable CF to  datatype comparisons.
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html

Be careful when using date masking. Differnt systems do different things, and "y" can be different from "Y", even in ColdFusion.

Also, on a general code review note: Please validate your inputs (especially the table name) and use a maxlength argument in your queryparam. insertData() looks very injectable. Also, if this is CF >9, don't use var local. The LOCAL scope is now built into ColdFusion. It shouldn't break anything, but you're not really doing what your code thinks it's doing.

Comment: *insertData() looks very injectable.*  Agreed. Also, is there a reason you must use dynamic SQL? Dynamic sql always seems like a great idea, but is very difficult to do it safely and *well*. IMO it almost always ends up costing more in terms of troubleshooting and maintenance time than it actually saves. This thread being a good example.

Comment: I have found that if you need to build dynamic sql, it's a lot easier and cleaner to build up a SQL string in script cf than tag cf. But that's just me. That said, I'd probably still do this in a sproc instead.

Comment: Usually I prefer stored procs for complex logic too. However, it is very easy to accidentally create a big sql injection portal if you are not careful when handling dynamic sql ;-) I have seen a LOT of legacy apps like that. `stored procedure != safe`.